# Extract and create a new email column dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a df with a column with emails and more information that I don't want. Here are some examples:

```
                                       Email_Col
"Snow, John" <john.snow@stackoverflow.com>, "Stark, Arya" <starkarya@got.com>
"YourBoss" <yourbosss1@yourcurrentcompany.net>
"test1 <emailtest@tester.com>", "test2 <emailtest2@tester.com>", "test3" <emailtest3@tester.com>
```

I need to clean the column or create a new one with the emails. Here the expected output, an array column:

```
                           New_Email_Col
[john.snow@stackoverflow.com, Stark, starkarya@got.com]
[yourbosss1@yourcurrentcompany.net]
[emailtest@tester.com emailtest2@tester.com, emailtest3@tester.com]
```

My code:

```py
import re

def extract(col):
    for row in col:
        all_matches = re.findall(r'\w+.\w+@\w+.\w+', row)
    return all_matches

extract_udf = udf(lambda col: extract(col), ArrayType(StringType()))

df = df.withColumn(('emails'), extract_udf(col('to')))
```

My error:

> PythonException: 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object', from , line 4. Full traceback below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refrain from `udf` - they are slow and nowadays not needed in the vast majority of cases. The following does the trick:

```py
F.expr("regexp_extract_all(Email_Col, '(?<=<).*?(?=>)', 0)")
```

[`regexp_extract_all`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract_all) is available from Spark 3.1+

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('''"Snow, John" <john.snow@stackoverflow.com>, "Stark, Arya" <starkarya@got.com>''',),
     ('''"YourBoss" <yourbosss1@yourcurrentcompany.net>''',),
     ('''"test1 <emailtest@tester.com>", "test2 <emailtest2@tester.com>", "test3" <emailtest3@tester.com>''',)],
    ['Email_Col'])

df = df.withColumn('Email_Col', F.expr("regexp_extract_all(Email_Col, '(?<=<).*?(?=>)', 0)"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |Email_Col                                                           |
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[john.snow@stackoverflow.com, starkarya@got.com]                    |
# |[yourbosss1@yourcurrentcompany.net]                                 |
# |[emailtest@tester.com, emailtest2@tester.com, emailtest3@tester.com]|
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To add a separate new column:

```py
df = df.withColumn('New_Email_Col', F.expr("regexp_extract_all(Email_Col, '(?<=<).*?(?=>)', 0)"))
```